# How to resolve adb: connect error for write : closed

Tags: android, adb, appium, appium-android

I am getting the list of adb devices. But when I try to install the apk I get error:

> connect error for write: closed

Image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBVb8.png]

Comment: share your error directly instead of image

Comment: can try this command first "adb usb"

Comment: which adb version are you using?

Comment: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\broy\\Downloads\\android-sdk-windows\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.android.chrome' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: closed'; Code: '1'

Comment: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 28.0.2-5303910
Installed as C:\Users\broy\Downloads\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe

Comment: Is the command prompt opened with  Admin privileges?

Comment: Since there's only one attached device, the -s emulator-554 parameters are not necessary

Comment: Also, try with -g parameter

Answer (score 0):

you should just use "apply update from adb" in recovery mode for installing new OS versions or something. 
If you just want to install an .apk, start the device normally, activate the developer options and after that activate usb-debugging. Then try again adb devices and after that you could install the .apk, while the device is started "normally" (no recovery mode). 
Hope this helps